# The Batch Geocoder API returns only failed status

Tags: c#, here-api, geocoder

I experience an issue with the Here Batch Geocoder Api.

I have tried with different input data and input parameters with not success so far.

I send a request with action run, like:

```
http://batch.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/jobs?action=run&app_code={app_code_value}&app_id={app_id_valeu}&outdelim=|&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel&outputcombined=false&indelim=|
```

The request data is:

```
recId|searchText|country
0001|Invalidenstraße 116 10115 Berlin|DEU
0002|Am Kronberger Hang 8 65824 Schwalbach|DEU
0003|425 W Randolph St Chicago IL 60606|USA
0004|One Main Street Cambridge MA 02142|USA
0005|200 S Mathilda Ave Sunnyvale CA 94086|USA
```

The Request Headers:
Content-Type:text/plain

The response is with status "accepted" which is fine but after I check the status with

```
https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs/{id}/?action=status&app_id={app_id_value}&app_code={app_code_Value}
```

The returned status is always failed.

Comment: You need to add real value to URL for items inside curly brackets.  {id} {app_id_value} {app_code_Value}

Comment: Before I post the question I have removed the actual values and replace them with the {id} {app_id_value} {app_code_Value}.

Comment: If you put URL manually into a browser does it work?  I want to make sure the id is valid.

Comment: The first request is post but the second with the status is a get request. I have tested it in the browser directly, with javascript as well as with c# but the result was the same.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SearchBatch xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Batch/1">
    <Response>
        <MetaInfo>
            <RequestId>uLJm72DwJTwFv3OfDL0A82AZw9ySEtwM</RequestId>
        </MetaInfo>
        <Status>failed</Status>
        <TotalCount>0</TotalCount>
        <ValidCount>0</ValidCount>
        <InvalidCount>0</InvalidCount>
        <ProcessedCount>0</ProcessedCount>
        <PendingCount>0</PendingCount>
        <SuccessCount>0</SuccessCount>
        <ErrorCount>0</ErrorCount>
    </Response>
</ns2:SearchBatch>`

Comment: You can try to re-run the job - see also here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/job-status.html#job-status  Another possibility to debug this a bit furhter would be to have a  look for the error. The parameter is here described: https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/endpoints.html

Comment: According to the documentation if I use:
`jobs/{REQUEST_ID}?action=run&params=...`
I should be able to rerun the failed request.
What should I put for the value of "params"?

Answer (score 0):

> id you url-encode the pipe symbol in 'indelim' and 'outdelim', e.g. "indelim=%7C" ?

See also https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/request-encoding.html